# How to do a portrait and landscape OSX app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, orientation

Hi I have to develop a Cocoa app for OSX with both orientations (landscape and portrait). My first idea is when the app finish launch to check the screen resolution to see if it is portrait or landscape and then show the landscape view or the portrait view. The views have the same elements, the only difference is the position of them. How do you think is the best way of accomplish this? Two views with two controllers? one controller with two views? Any advise would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Landscape OS X app ? Did you mean iOS (iPhone/iPad) app ?

Comment: No, OSX app. It is an app that is going to be run on different screens resolutions, so I would need one for 1920x1080 (that would be "landscape" version) and another one for 1080*1920 (that would be "portrait")

Comment: I think you ought be checking the size of the NSWindow rather than the screen

Comment: Why/how would someone use OS X in portrait? All Mac screens are bigger horizontally than they are vertically.... so this question makes no sense?? Maybe you are asking to know if the user has done a software screen rotation? (Like you can do in Windows too)??

Comment: Hi Jef, the checking code is fine, it detects fine the resolution. And Dan, it is an app for displaying content purposes so it is going to be run on a mac and displayed in different screens with different resolutions.

Comment: Landscape/Portrait term in this context is misleading. You should be looking at how to restructure your views to make it adaptive to the window size.

Comment: You can keep different xib's or story board's in this case . Check your resolution and load appropriate xib or storyboard.

Comment: I think others have covered well the fact that this is the wrong line of thinking for a Mac app. Let your user decide their window geometry within whatever sizing constraints you define (such as some enforced aspect ratio). On a Mac, place as few restrictions on window sizes/positions as possible. I'd quickly delete an app that forced some window layout on me that it clearly didn't need to.